# How does the class of the tangent bundle behave in the K-theory ring?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

Seeing as the tangent bundle of a manifold is an important object in differential geometry, I was wondering if it has any specific behavior in the K-theory of a manifold.  (Either real/complex, reduced/otherwise I'm guessing it doesn't make a difference).
For example, does the tangent bundle generate an interesting ideal in the $K$-ring?  Is it radical?  Prime?  Is it a nilpotent element?